# Solidity & React Next.js Error not fetching Contract [NPM]

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, solidity, package.json

I'm trying to build an NFT Market place.

For some reason,  `npm run dev` stopped working after I exited VSCode (was running completely fine yesterday). Even tried to work on it today and had the same error but then deleted **node_modules** & **package-lock.json** and then reinstalled using `npm install` and it worked fine.
But retrying the same thing now it's not working at all and won't let me fetch my functions from **NFTMarketPlace.sol**.

*(I put below all the appropriate code I believe might help)*
**Please help** me fix this. I'm new to React/Next.js.
Thank you!

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.2",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "hardhat": "^2.8.4",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^56.0.1",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  }
}
```

**Error messages:** 
[image: Console log][image: React Error]

**index.js [Part of it ] **

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";

import { marketplaceAddress } from "../config";

import NFTMarketplace from "../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol/NFTMarketplace.json";

export default function Home() {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState("not-loaded");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFTs();
  }, []);

  async function loadNFTs() {
    /* create a generic provider and query for unsold market items */
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      marketplaceAddress,
      NFTMarketplace.abi,
      provider
    );
    const data = await contract.fetchMarketItems();
```

Comment: First place I check when I have issues like this is with your version of node. Use nvm to manage them and make sure you're not on the bleeding edge - use v16 or even v14. Reinstall all your packages again after you fix this and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I realised my mistake... As I was running the test on hardhat I had to deploy using `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost` instead of `node scripts/deploy.js`

So to run the dev script i had to do the following commands:

```
npx hardhat node
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
npm run dev
```